# How to push array position in the array faster

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet data in form of array. Now I want to push the array position I used for loop which is working fine on small data but when the data length is increased it result in delay.
Is there a faster way to push the array position in the array.

Here is the code which I am currently using:-

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxOI');
 var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
 var data = sheet1.getRange("A:H").getValues();
 var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
  {
  data.unshift(i+1);
 } // this for loop takes too much time.

  data = data.filter(function(item){return item[7] == email});


  var x = data.map(function(val){
    return val.slice(0, -7);
 }) 
  Logger.log(x)
  return x;

}
```

Comment: Did you mean `data[i].unshift(i+1)` ?

Comment: ahh right!!, but again it may delay if the rows are in thousands

Comment: I guess I missed to put that in there Thank you. Currently the job is done in 2 sec is there any faster way?

Comment: ``filter`` first and then `unshift`/unshift inside map before slice

Comment: but then I will not get the real position. I am counting google sheet row as position.

Comment: unshift inside filter then. `data.filter((item,i) => item[7] == email && item.unshift(i+1));
`

Comment: I did as you instruct but time does not seem to be affected. That means either I write it outside filter or inside filter the loop is going to run same number of times. Its just the code look shorter now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- If `data.unshift(i+1)` is `data[i].unshift(i+1)` as [TheMaster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62085675/how-to-push-array-position-in-the-array-faster#comment109807819_62085675), you want to retrieve the values of the column "A" when the value of column "G" is the same with `email`. At that time, you want to add the row number to the 1st index of the row value.

  - From your script, I understood like this.
- You want to reduce the process cost of this situation.

For this problem, how about this solution?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script is modified. In this case, the result values are retrieve by one loop.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxOI');
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var data = sheet1.getRange("A1:H" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();  // Modified
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  const res = data.reduce((ar, [a,,,,,,g], i) => {  // Modified
    if (g == email) ar.push([i + 1, a]);
    return ar;
  }, []);

  Logger.log(res)
  return res;
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, as other method, TextFinder and Sheets API are used. In this case, the size of base data by searching `email` with TextFinder can be reduced. And each values are retrieved by one API call using Sheets API.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheetId = '19zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxOI';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  // 1. Retrieve the ranges of rows by searching "email" at the column "G".
  const ranges = sheet.getRange("G1:G" + sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(email).findAll();

  // 2. Create an object for using with Sheets API.
  const reqs = ranges.reduce((o, e) => {
    const row = e.getRow();
    o.rows.push(row);
    o.ranges.push("A" + row);
    return o;
  }, {rows: [], ranges: []});

  // 3. Retrieve values and add the row number.
  const res = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(spreadsheetId, {ranges: reqs.ranges})
    .valueRanges
    .map((e, i) => ([reqs.rows[i], e.values[0][0]]));

  Logger.log(res)
  return res;
}
```

- If `email` is included other string, please use `matchEntireCell(true)` to TextFinder.

### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)

Comment: Do you provide online classes? I would like to be your student. How can I contact you?

Comment: Yes your answer reduced by time consumption from 2.08 sec to 1.2 sec. But please provide your mail address for future.

Comment: @Mask: while we cannot prevent people from exchanging contact details, the purpose of Stack Overflow is to maintain a catalogue of well-written questions and answers for future readers, and private support channels tend to work against that. My experience is that private support can become substantially burdensome for the helper, and takes up time that would previously have helped many more people.

Comment: Sure I will take care of that in future.